# PowerBi Distinctcount not working properly with 3 measures

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am having an issue using the Distinctcount function in DAX.  I have a table with a total of 1,154,493 rows.  I have a measure created to count the number of distinct values in column 1.  I have another measure created to count the number of distinct values in column 1 with filters. I have a 3rd and final measure created to count the number of distinct values of column 1 with different filters. The issue I am running into is the count of measure 2 + measure 3 should equal measure 1 however added together they are GREATER than the value of measure 1 which is just a grand total.  How is this possible?  Unfortunately I can't share the table but below is the code I am using for the two measures:

```
Measure1=distinctcount('Table1'[Column1])
Measure2=calculate(distinctcount('Table1'[Column1]),'Table1'[CTest] = 1,'Table1'[CTest2] = "07")
Measure3=calculate(distinctcount('Table1'[Column1]),'Table1'[CTest] = 2,'Table1'[CTest2] = "07")
```

I am at a loss.  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Is column1 Unique? How many rows do you have? ROWCOUNT('Table')
If it is not I don't see  why adding 2 field that can be counted multiple times be equal to its distinct value... For troubleshooting you should identify values of Column1 with Measure2 and Measure3 > 0, those are being added twice

Comment: Turns out there was another column in the table that was impacting the results.  I used your troubleshooting method to find the problem, thank you very much!  If you submit this as an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For troubleshooting you should identify values of Column1 with Measure2 and Measure3 > 0, those are being added twice.